# Convert string with comma into number

Tags: string, oracle, numbers, extract

I'm trying to sum XML attribute amount with values like 7819.3 and 156.90 with this query

```
SELECT J.NUMERO_ELETTRONICO, TO_NUMBER((SELECT * FROM XMLTABLE( xmlnamespaces('http://www.hp.com/best/next/trx' as "trx"),'sum(//trx:Contanti/trx:Taglio[@valoreNominale="0"]/@amount)' passing I.OPERATION_DOC )))
```

but I obtain results like this

```
93218214                                 8.0E+03
```

I tried using TO_NUMBER format attributes like these

```
TO_NUMBER('7,9761999999999998E+003','999999G99', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=''.,''')
```

but I can't obtain 7.976 as number.

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: The question makes no sense. Numbers don't have a format. The result you get in the query is probably correct; what you need is to DISPLAY that number in some specific format, and that is done with TO_CHAR, not with TO_NUMBER. Also - please explain what is the decimal separator and what is the "thousands" separator for you; in one place you show 7819.3, suggesting the period is the decimal separator, but then you show 7.976 as number where it's 8.0E+03 which suggests you are using the period as the thousands separator.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved with this query

```
SELECT J.NUMERO_ELETTRONICO, TO_CHAR(TO_NUMBER((SELECT * FROM XMLTABLE( xmlnamespaces('http://www.hp.com/best/next/trx' as "trx"),'sum(//trx:Contanti/trx:Taglio[@valoreNominale="0"]/@amount)' passing I.OPERATION_DOC ))), '9999.99') AS AMOUNT
```